# Who sends the 8B command sequence to UART? Hardware or Serial Terminal?

Tags: embedded, uart

I read the following in Functional specification of a SoC

"Boot from UART is activated when the following 8B command sequence is detected on one of the available serial ports.
0xBB,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77"

Is the above 8B command sequence sent by Teraterm? or some hardware sends this byte sequence?

Comment: Either is possible.  But it would be easiest to use a small custom program, as those codes include non-printable ones which may require tricks to enter in a terminal.  Note that you will need to follow up with the binary data of the program you wish to boot, possibly in a special format.  Likely someone has already written and published source of a tool to do that.

Comment: You'll want a terminal which can send raw data and in which you can type hex. The other option is to write down a little snippet on any MCU board you happen to have and send it from there.